# How to search an enum in list of strings by postgresql query?

Tags: java, postgresql, enums, sql-in

Consider a SQL Statement:

```
select * from table where status in <statuses>
```

Where status is an enum:

```
CREATE TYPE statusType AS ENUM (
  'enum1',
  'enum2';
```

In Java I have a list of the enums in string representation:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("enum1");
list.add("enum2");
```

I then try to build and execute the query using SqlStatement:

```
handle.createQuery("select * from table where status in <statuses>")
                    .bindList("statuses", statuses)
                    .map(Mapper.instance)
                    .list());
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToExecuteStatementException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: status = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've tried wrapping each list item with CAST(enum1 as statusType) or enum1::statusType but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this `select * from table where status::text in <statuses>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the enum to text

```
handle.createQuery("select * from table where status::text in <statuses>")
                .bindList("statuses", statuses)
                .map(Mapper.instance)
                .list());
```