# org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Superfluous named parameters provided while the query declares none

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbi3

```
@SqlQuery("Select id from user where type in (<CAST(userType as user_type[])>)")
List<Long> getUserIdsByListOfTypes(@BindList("userType") List<User.UserType> userType);
```

I want to fetch the list of Ids from the List of userTypes.
Here User.UserType is an enum. In the method(getUserIdsByListOfTypes), I am passing the parameter(userTypes) of type list of enum.
I am not able to understand where is the problem in the query.

Comment: Solution which works for me:  ```@SqlQuery("Select id from user where type::text in (<userType>)")
List<Long> getUserIdsByListOfTypes(@BindList("userType") List<String> userType);```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking list of enum type, I had taken the list of string.

```
@SqlQuery("Select id from user where type::text in (<userType>)")   
List<Long> getUserIdsByListOfTypes(@BindList("userType") List<String> userType);
```

[How to search an enum in list of strings by postgresql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550604/how-to-search-an-enum-in-list-of-strings-by-postgresql-query)